# Read out and display contents of txt file in list form

Tags: php

I have a script that lists all txt files in a folder. What i want to do is to display the file contents instead of the filename. but i dont succeed... i tried readfile and filegetcontents but i get only .txt name

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('../plugins/guestbook/news/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "<center><label class='tablog3a'>$file <div style='float: right;margin-top:10px;'><a href='gbremove.php?file=".$file."'><img src='images/deletegb.png' title='Verwijder afbeelding' class='clickreverse'></a></div></label></center>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

i tried also

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('../plugins/guestbook/news/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
$txtfile = file_get_contents('$file');
            echo "<center><label class='tablog3a'>$txtfile<div style='float: right;margin-top:10px;'><a href='gbremove.php?file=".$file."'><img src='images/deletegb.png' title='Verwijder afbeelding' class='clickreverse'></a></div></label></center>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `fopen` and `fread`? http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

Comment: i edited my post whi my try, i only get blank lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php 
$dir = "your_directory/"; // Your directory

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      // Check for .txt files
      if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, -3) == "txt") {
        // Open file to read
        $fp = fopen($dir.$file, 'r');

        // Print contents
        echo fread($fp, filesize($dir.$file)).'<br />';
      }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}?>
```

cheers

Comment: @Johan Sidenote: You can exclude files also adding `&& $file != "exclude_me.txt"` `&& $file != "exclude_me_also.txt"`